# Ubuntu 20.04 - Monitors keep waking up every 10 seconds when computer is locked

Tags: gnome, 20.04, suspend, lock-screen

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on my Desktop Machine, and when I lock the computer, it never goes to sleep. I noticed the monitors go to sleep and wake up every 10 seconds indefinitely. This is pretty bad for power consumption and I was wondering what could cause this issue and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the PC stays suspended/shutdown but the monitors wake up? What make/model are the monitors? Have you checked the monitor own built-in power-saving options, usually via the monitors buttons/on-screen interface? How are the monitors connected to the PC? VGA? HMDI? DisplayPort? Are there any USB cables going to/from the monitors or USB hubs in the monitors?

Comment: @codlord PC is still running after being locked, and monitors are plugged via HDMI and Display port with no accessories plugged to them. There is no issue when booting on windows.

Comment: I've experienced this with multi monitor setup. My thought is the power management on one or all of the monitors kicks in and suspends the monitor, this changes the number of displays connected to the OS. Because the OS now sees only say 1 display, it tries to adjust the window manager for 1 display. When this happens, the monitors wake up and the OS readjusts the window manager for two displays. And this cycle keeps on repeating.